# SQL left join gives wrong results

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In table `A` (i.e. `Charges`) I have my data and in `B` (i.e `gdh`) there are mappings.

For some reason my query doesn't show rows without mappings with null value.
Any thoughts?

```
select a.chargeable_object, a.debitor, a.source_bu, a.target_cc, a.target_bu, b.L5_CLUSTER, sum(a.charge)
from charges a
    left join gdh b on a.target_cc = b.department_id
where a.account not like ('H%')
  and a.chargeable_object is not null
  and a.source_bu in ('301','161','303')
  and a.debitor not in ('0315X02', '0961901', '0972023', '0972024',......)
group by a.chargeable_object, a.debitor, a.source_bu, a.target_cc, a.target_bu, b.L5_CLUSTER
```

Comment: You are not filtering from gdh so the problem is is your data I think. We can not help without some data to reproduce problem.

Comment: It is not clear: do you want to include mappings with null values or not?

Comment: At a guess, it's because all the rows in your charges table that match the where conditions all have a corresponding row in the gdh table.

Comment: yes i want to include mapping with null values. when i query the data without join just from table A i get more than 2 milions rows,but with this join its only 1 mil where it should be basically the same .

Comment: Please update your question to include output data that shows the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: If you want to show rows of charges without a corresponding row in gdh then you should `left outer join`

Comment: @FrankOckenfuss I think `left join` is simply short for `left outer join`

Comment: @GeertBellekens thank you, my mistake :-)

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see some example data. Anyhow does the column a.target_cc contains null values? I would expect that those would be filtered out.